# TensorFlow example but with middle layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to get this code to work. It may not look like it, but it comes mostly from the TensorFlow mnist example. I am trying to get three layers, though, and I've changed the input and output size. The input size is 12, the mid size is 6, and the output size is 2. This is what happens when I run this. It does not throw an error, but when I run the test option I always get 50%. When I go back to training it runs and I am sure the weights are changing. There is code for saving the model and weights, so I'm pretty confident it's not wiping out my weights every time I re-start it. The idea behind self.d_y_out is to have something that will allow me to run the model and get output for just one image. I think the problem is near the comment that says "PROBLEM??".

```
        self.d_keep = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        self.d_W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([mid_num, output_num], stddev=0.0001))
        self.d_b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([output_num], stddev=0.5))

        self.d_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_num])
        self.d_W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_num, mid_num], stddev=0.0001))  # 0.0004
        self.d_b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([mid_num]))

        self.d_y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, output_num])

        self.d_x_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.d_x, self.d_keep)

        self.d_y_logits_1 = tf.matmul(self.d_x_drop, self.d_W_1) + self.d_b_1
        self.d_y_mid = tf.nn.relu(self.d_y_logits_1) 
        self.d_y_mid_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.d_y_mid, self.d_keep)

        self.d_y_logits_2 = tf.matmul(self.d_y_mid_drop, self.d_W_2) + self.d_b_2

        self.d_y_softmax = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.d_y_logits_2, labels=self.d_y_)

        self.d_cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(self.d_y_softmax) ## PROBLEM??

        self.d_train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(self.d_cross_entropy)  # 0.0001

        # train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy) #0.5

        #self.d_y_out = tf.argmax(self.d_y, 1)  ## for prediction
        self.d_y_out = tf.argmax(self.d_y_logits_2, 1, name="d_y_out")

    if self.train :

        for i in range(self.start_train,self.cursor_tot): #1000
            batch_xs, batch_ys = self.get_nn_next_train(self.batchsize)
            self.sess.run(self.d_train_step, feed_dict={self.d_x: batch_xs, self.d_y_: batch_ys, self.d_keep: 0.5})
            if True: #mid_num > 0:
                cost = self.sess.run([self.d_cross_entropy, self.d_train_step], 
                    feed_dict={self.d_x: batch_xs, self.d_y_: batch_ys, self.d_keep: 0.5})
                print cost[0], "cost"


    if self.test :
        d_correct_prediction = tf.equal(self.d_y_out, tf.argmax(self.d_y_,1))
        #d_correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.d_y , 1), tf.argmax(self.d_y_, 1))

        d_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(d_correct_prediction, tf.float32))

        if self.use_loader : self.get_nn_next_test(self.batchsize)
        print(self.sess.run([d_accuracy, self.d_cross_entropy], 
            feed_dict={self.d_x: self.mnist_test.images, self.d_y_: self.mnist_test.labels, self.d_keep: 1.0}))

    if self.predict_dot :
        for i in range(start, stop ) :
            batch_0, batch_1 = self.get_nn_next_predict(self.batchsize)
            if len(batch_0) > 0 :
                out.extend( self.sess.run([self.d_y_out, self.d_cross_entropy], 
                    feed_dict={self.d_x : batch_0, self.d_y_: batch_1, self.d_keep: 1.0})[0])
                print "out" , len(out) , i, self.cursor_tot, out[:10],"..."
```

**EDIT** I've edited the code in this question significantly. Much thanks to vijay m for getting me this far. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you observing on your loss? Does `d_cross_entropy_2` decrease at every training step?.  The problem in your code seems to be the large learning rate. Change the gradient decent learning rate from 2 to a lower number say 0.01.

Comment: with only part of an epoch, and the rate set to 0.01, the test value doesn't change from 0.5. A full epoch might take an hour, though. How would I check `d_cross_entropy_2` and print the value to check if it always is decreasing?

Comment: get the cost using : cost, _ = self.sess.run([self.d_cross_entropy_2, self.d_train_step], feed_dict={self.d_x: batch_xs, self.d_y_: batch_ys})

Comment: ok. I'm getting some results with learning rate set to 0.1 , I also printed the cost as you directed. Should I go with that rate or should I try 0.01 even though my results are not as apparent?

Comment: Look at the cost, if it decreases very slowing that u can increase a bit, but if it oscillates then u can decrease it. You should train longer as long as your validation loss is decreasing.

Comment: the cost is decreasing to a certain point and then learning just stops and the cost stops decreasing. I get 0.5 output from 'test'. I don't even get the success I had before with learning set to 0.1. I don't know why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148645/discussion-between-vijay-m-and-d-liebman).

Comment: I still get 0.5 for my test output. I've edited this question alot since yesterday. Please take a look. This code runs without thowing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this code is you calling `dropout` on the inputs. Yours is a single layer network and you don't need `dropout`. And use a momentum optimizer like `Adam` for training faster. The changes i made:

```
d_y_logits_1 = tf.matmul(d_x, d_W_1) + d_b_1
d_y_mid = tf.nn.relu(d_y_logits_1) 

d_y_logits_2 = tf.matmul(d_y_mid, d_W_2) + d_b_2

d_y_softmax = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=d_y_logits_2, labels=d_y_)

d_cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(d_y_softmax)

d_train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(d_cross_entropy)
```

Comment: There's some problem because I still get 0.5 for the output, regardless of how much or little training I do. The output of self.d_y_out is always a list of ones. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: i got an accuracy of >0.9

Comment: I don't know. my training set is skin tones. 1 for skin, 0 for something else. (in this case just some other part of the picture). I've got a lot of pictures set up this way. I had a single layer NN and that picked up the color differences well. This should work too. I think I've got an error in the test code.

Comment: what are the loss values during training, started with what and ended with what?

Comment: start with 0.7 approx and end around 0.6931

Comment: come to the discussion chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148696/discussion-between-d-liebman-and-vijay-m).

Comment: thanks. !! This worked for me so far. I still have the 0.5 problem sometimes.